# Puppet Windows Package Provider Encoding Error

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding, puppet

I have a Puppet manifest for Windows that is used (among other things) to download and install Python. It used to work just fine. Now it's giving me strange errors related to string encoding whenever it tries to process an MSI file. The relevant portions of the manifest are:

(Note: I'm using [pget](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/cyberious/pget) to download the MSI. )

```
# Prepare to download things

$downloads = "C:\\puppet-downloads"

file { $downloads:
    ensure => directory
}
Pget {
    require => File[$downloads],
    target  => $downloads,
}

$python      = 'python'
$py_version  = '2.7.10'
$py_dir      = "C:\\Python27"
$py_msi      = "python-${py_version}.msi"
$py_msi_path = "${downloads}\\${py_msi}"

pget {'python-msi':
    source => "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${py_version}/${py_msi}",
}

package {$python:
   require  => Pget['python-msi'],
   provider => 'windows',
   source   => $py_msi_path,
   ensure   => $py_version,
}
```

And the error output:

> Error: Could not prefetch package provider 'windows': U+2122 to IBM437 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM437
>
> Error: /Package[python]: Could not evaluate: U+2122 to IBM437 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM437

What I've figured out:

- U+2122 is the trademark character (™)
- The format of the error is from a Ruby string conversion function rather than anything Puppet-specific.
- The error occurs even when this portion of the manifest is run all by itself.
- The debug output for puppet apply lists "default_encoding = IBM437" near the beginning, but I haven't found any way to change that setting:

> Debug: Runtime environment: puppet_version=3.7.5, ruby_version=2.1.5, run_mode=user, default_encoding=IBM437

Comment: I tried running that code on a Windows VM and it worked for me: https://gist.github.com/petems/33ccc2d7171c07159f89 Can you try running `facter -p`, as it's possible the TM symbol is from the facts on the system.

Comment: I ran the command from powershell and the output started with this message: "Could not retrieve fact='network_local_area_connection', resolution='<anonymous>': undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass"

Then I piped the output to a text file. The file begins with (in hex) 0xFF 0xFE which I believe is called a "byte order mark." Other than that I don't see any non-ascii characters in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's actually a ticket open for this: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-4333

It looks like the problem is packages already installed with non-compatible characters, and it tries to pre-fetch what's already installed:

Workaround for now (from the ticket):

- Run "wmic product get name"
- Find those that have non-ascii characters
- Removing the odd looking characters from the registry

Comment: I'm glad the bug is known and that it's considered urgent. However the output of that command doesn't show any non-ascii characters, although when I pipe it to a file it gets the same 0xFF 0xFE as with my other comment above with facter -r. This happens whether I use Cmd or Powershell and no matter what the current console encoding is.

Comment: I spoke too soon. Although the output for `wmic product get name` does not _appear_ to show any unicode characters, the listing for Skype had an uppercase "T" in it. So just to be sure, I uninstalled it and, sure enough, the error went away. (Although it revealed some errors with other packages...I'll consider  that a separate issue though)

Comment: @BHarms Another workaround to consider is using the Chocolatey provider instead. Here's why - https://forge.puppetlabs.com/chocolatey/chocolatey#why-chocolatey

Comment: Actually, I started with the Chocolatey provider before this. The problem is that it would always crash with error code '1603' when attempting to install Python2 via chocolatey, with or without Puppet. and from what I can tell others have shared this issue. Supposedly it was fixed but it still happens on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Running `chcp 65001` in the command prompt will change your console encoding to UTF-8.

I don't know how that will fit into your workflow though.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Ruby but Puppet is being invoked from a PowerShell script. Does ruby default to the encoding of the shell it was invoked from?

Comment: Yes, some libraries, like RDoc, even go as far as to change the default encoding to UTF-8 to avoid problems with non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in one of my infrastructure laptops and it was the only one with Skype™ 7.0 installed. I did a search in the registry and removed that TM from every key with DisplayName or ProductName. It worked. However I backed up just in case. So I confirm that you can check whether one of your installed programs has this chars in the name, so you can remove in Windows Registry. Just be careful though.